How to compute a confidence interval with an inaccurate evaluator?
Let's consider the following prompt for an LLM:

System prompt: You are an expert in Python language. Your role is to answer to any Python related question.
User prompt: <User query>

I want to test this system prompt to check if it correctly answers to the questions of the user. For that, I have created a dataset of questions:

In which module is the sqrt function?
What function could I use to lower the characters of a string?
...

This dataset contains 5421 questions. I have fed my LLM with this dataset, and I got 5421 answers. I have reviewed 43 of them and I have evaluated each answer with a PASS/FAIL evaluation. An answer is considered PASS if it correctly answers to the question of the user. Among these 43 answers, I have found 24 PASS answers.
I want now that another LLM evaluates this system prompt. For that, I created an LLM-as-a-judge as an evaluator. The role is this LLM-as-a-judge will be to perform the same task I did on the 43 answers: evaluate each answer with a PASS/FAIL evaluation.
I fed the LLM-as-a-judge with the 43 questions/answers that I have already evaluated. I have found that this judge agreed with me 79% of the time.
Then, I fed the LLM-as-a-judge with all the 5421 questions/answers of my dataset. The LLM-as-a-judge evaluates the system prompt with a score of 87.12% (meaning that 87.12% of the answers of the system prompt are evaluated to PASS).
Now, as the LLM-as-a-judge is 79% accurate (meaning that it does not always evaluates like me), I would like to know what score I would have given to the entire dataset (knowing that the judge gave a score of 87.12%).
How can I compute this score? Is it possible to determine a confidence interval around 87.12%?
Note: I'm new to statistics and apologize if this question has been answered before. I find it difficult to understand some of the existing questions and answers. Please keep your answer simple.

The "evaluation" is basically an optimization problem that is performed behind. The model wants to minimize an error (i.e. maximize a likelihood). Additionally, you should add to your post an extract of your code, in particular the method you used to evaluate your llm. It's important because there are couple of functions to do so. The way the errors are computed might change depending on the library you use. So please, provide the libraries you used.

To evaluate my LLM, I just compare its evaluation to mine. Over the 42 items I have manually evaluated, the LLM has the same evaluation (which is a binary evaluation) 79% of the time.

I don't understand. What does the last sentence in your first paragraph mean? What is "the evaluator"? What is "mine"? In the next paragraph is "success" an evaluation?

The "evaluator" is the LLM-as-a-judge."mine" is the evaluation I performed myself. "success" is when the initial LLM, the one I want to evaluate, produce an answer that fits to the criteria I have defined when creating my LLM-as-a-judge.

This is on all fours with "I did a quiz and got 16/20 answers correct". To get a confidence interval for that you need to cast the problem in probability terms. For example, you could compare your result with the distribution of possibilities based on random guessing. In your case, I doubt that random guessing is a useful reference condition, but you need some better model. Minimally, you need to evaluate your procedure repeatedly to get an idea of its statistical behaviour.

However, to compute a confident interval, you would need this evaluation to be computed from a stochastic distribution. Indeed, there is no empirical estimation of such a value.

Could you give an example in your answer? I have no idea of how to compute that.

@PeterFlom I add more details to my question.

This will not really be an answer to the question(s?) asked,l because I do not thinbk that there are ways to get what you seem to want. Consider these a series of comments, and possible suggestion, around the problem you presented.
You ask "I would like to know what score I would have given to the entire dataset". Well the trivial answer is: 79.1%. But that would be absolutely wrong; you only scored 43 questions, out of 5421, so your 79.1% is just an estimate, and certainly not t he exact percentage you would have gotten if you had scored all 5421 questions. But we can compute a confidence interval (CI) for this score (binomial confidence interval of a proportion); you obtain [63.96%,89.96%], so pretty wide (26 percentage points). And it is so wide because a total of 43 trials for a dichotomous variable is actually a pretty small sample size. So your 79.1% is not really 79.1% (the true value could be anywhere in that interval).
Similarly, the 87.12% of the LLM-judge is only an estimate of the actual, true pass rate the LLM-judge would obtain on all future questions. We can similarly compute a CI for the LLM-judge; we obtain [86.20%,88.00%]. Much tighter (because of the much larger sample size). You can also note that this CI is entirely included in the first CI.
Well, now we can run a test to compare these 2 proportions ($\chi^2$ test, z test -which is exactly the same as $\chi^2$-, or Fisher exact). When you do this, you do not get a statistically significant result on any of the tests: e.g., for a z-test, the p-value is .059 for a single sided test, or .117 for a double sided test. The p-values are low, so the 2 proportions are not very similar, but still close enough (at the traditional $\alpha=.05$ significance level).
Now do not conclude that this shows that the LLM-judge scores similarly to you. That woudl be the wrong interpretation. All you have done is failed to prove (at the .05 significance level) that they are different. Very different. To illustrate this, let's pretend that you scored 86 questions manually (twice as many), and obtained exactly the same proportion (79.1%). In that case, all tests (Z, $\chi^2$ Fisher exact, single or double sided) are all significant (at the .05 significance level). Now you can say, with 95% confidence, that the LLM-judge does not score like you. The reason that did not show up eallier is simply the low sample size. So I am pretty convinced that if you manually scored ~100-120 questions, the tests would show a significant difference; that is, the LLM-judge is not scoring as you do.
Typically, when training, or testing, such an expert system, one uses "experts" to provide he ground truth. It is not clear from your question whether you are such an expert, or not... Moreover, one usually uses multiple experts (3 or more), as experts will disagree on some items (and then you can use a consensus rule, or a majority rule, to get the "true" answer). But here you used only 1 expert. Given the above it is not clear that 79.1% is the actual truth about the 43 items. What if another "expert" looked at the same 43 answers? Would he/she agree with all your scores? Unlikely... You do not seem to have such a ground truth; this makes determining right from wrong a challenge...
A few suggestions; first, score a few more question from the first LLM yourself (to get to at least ~100-120, idealy ~200?), and then compute the CI's, and run the tests as above. This should show that you can not use the LLM-judge to avoid having to score all 5421 answers from the first LLM.
You could also ask the LLM-judge to only score the 43 you scored; that will give you an idea of how similar, or not, the scoring is. But as I said, 43 is a small sample size for a dichotomous test. So you should, again, score more, and then compare these to the LLM-judge. Also, examining case by case where and why the 2 disagreed could be informative.
But when it comes to what I think is your ultimate goal (avoiding the tedious task of scoring all 5421 answers from the 1st LLM), I am afraid that it will not be possible, as the judge will be significantly (in the statistical sense) different from you. Moreover, having a single "expert" (you) validate the first LLM does not seem like best practice? It is not clear who the audience is for the results, and whether they would accept the methodology?

Thanks for your interesting answer. Just a few remarks: the 79.1% score is obtained when I compared the LLM-as-a-judge with my evaluation on the 43 items I evaluated. On the other hand, my evaluation was 24/43=56%. I have been indeed the only expert to evaluate these items, I followed the methodology in the article I mentioned in my question. I am surprised when you say "I am afraid that it will not be possible" because LLM-as-a-judge seems today one of the best alternative to measure the reliability of an LLM.

If you found 24/43 of the 1st LLM answers to be correct, and the LLM-judge found 4723/5421 to be correct, any test of 2 proportions will tell you that this is a (very) significant difference (p<=.000001) (even with the low sample size!). So the LLM-judge does not rate as you would; so you can not use it... (unless you want to claim that the LLM-judge is more of an expert than you are? But then why score it yourself, why compare the LLM-judge to you?)
